# How to alter a rule with Vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, webpack-chain

From `vue-inspect` I can read this:

```
  /* config.module.rule('fonts') */
  {
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/i,
    use: [
      /* config.module.rule('fonts').use('url-loader') */
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 4096,
          fallback: {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

I would like to change the option `name` to `'[name].[ext]'` to remove the prefix `fonts/`.

I am really struggling to see how I can alter the property without deleting all other options:

```
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const fontRule = config.module.rule('fonts').use('url-loader')
    fontRule.options({name: 'prout/[name].[ext]'})
  }
```

It seems everything is in `store`, but according to [webpack-chain](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain#getting-started) manual,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the vue-cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader) it seems to me you can do the following ..

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('fonts')
      .use('url-loader')
        .loader('url-loader')
        .tap(options => {
          // modify the options...
          options.fallback.options.name = '[name].[ext]'

          return options
        })
  }
}
```